# Meaning of "Lua does not perform the primitive assignment." in 2.4 (concerning __newindex)

Tags: api, lua, manual

from https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html
see section 2.4. Concerning the metamethod operation __newindex states the following quote:

> __newindex: The indexing assignment table[key] = value. Like the index event, this event happens when table is not a table or when key is not
> present in table. The metamethod is looked up in table.
>
> Like with indexing, the metamethod for this event can be either a
> function or a table. If it is a function, it is called with table,
> key, and value as arguments. If it is a table, Lua does an indexing
> assignment to this table with the same key and value. (This assignment
> is regular, not raw, and therefore can trigger another metamethod.)
>
> Whenever there is a __newindex metamethod, Lua does not perform the
> primitive assignment. (If necessary, the metamethod itself can call
> rawset to do the assignment.)

of that I ask what the follow specifically intends to say

> "Lua does not perform the
> primitive assignment. (If necessary, the metamethod itself can call
> rawset to do the assignment.)"

Does this mean that if the value is a number, which is a primitive, it will not be assigned to the provided table through the metamethod event and we have to use rawget or something? This is very confusing and contradictory to me.

Comment: Regular assignment = with invoking metamethods.  Primitive assignment = without invoking metamethods.  If you need primitive assignment you have to use `rawset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I want to show same examples to help you figure out this confusion.
The primitive assignment example:

```lua
local test = {}
test['x'] = 1 -- equal to rawset(test, 'x', 1)
print(test['x']) -- 1
print(rawget(test,'x')) -- 1
```

the primitive assignment code `test['x'] = 1` equal to `rawset(test, 'x', 1)` when the table `test` have no `__newindex`metamethod.

then the `__newindex` metamethod example:

```lua
local test = {}
setmetatable(test, {__newindex = function(t,key,value) end})
test['x'] = 1
print(test['x']) -- nil
print(rawget(test,'x')) -- nil
```

the assignment `test['x'] = 1` will trigger to call the `__newindex` function.
if `__newindex` do nothing, then nothing happens, we will get nil result of `test['x']`.

If the `__newindex` function call `rawset`:

```lua
local test = {}
setmetatable(test, {
  __newindex = function(t,key,value) 
                 rawset(t,key,value) -- t:test key:'x' value:1
               end})
test['x'] = 1
print(test['x']) -- 1
print(rawget(test,'x')) -- 1
```

the code have same effect as the first example.
So the manual say:

> "Lua does not perform the primitive assignment. (If necessary, the metamethod itself can call rawset to do the assignment.)"

Then the problem is, how we can use `__newindex`?
It can be used to separate the old and new index in table.

```
local test = {y = 1}
local newtest = {}
setmetatable(test, {
    __newindex = 
        function(t,key,value)
            newtest[key] = value
        end,
    __index = newtest
})

test["x"] = 1

print(test['x']) -- 1
print(test['y']) -- 1

print(rawget(test, 'x')) -- nil
print(rawget(test, 'y')) -- 1
```

the old index 'x' and new index 'y' can all be accessed by `test[key]`, and can be separated by `rawget(test, key)`